# Re-sizing Google chart in window

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, dom-events

Please help me how to automatically re-size the Google chart when the windows re-size too.

Here is some code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Day', 'Open ticket', 'Closed ticket'],
            ['Day 1',  10,   400],
            ['Day 2',  170,  460],
            ['Day 3',  60,   1120],
            ['Day 4',  30,   540],
        ]);
        var options = {
            title: 'DAILY GRAPH',
            hAxis: {title: 'NOVEMBER',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

Add this event handler:

```
 window.onresize = drawChart;
```

Then base the chart width and height on a percentage of the window's width and height:

```
    var width = .4 * window.innerHeight;
    var height = .4 * window.innerWidth;

    var options = {
        title: 'DAILY GRAPH',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        hAxis: { title: 'NOVEMBER', titleTextStyle: { color: '#333' } },
        vAxis: { minValue: 0 }
    };
```

Comment: what is the exact place i will put window.onresize = drawChart;?

Answer (score 4):

You can have `width` and `height` defined in percentages in `head` section, for example:

```
<style>
    #chart_div {
        width:  80%;
        height: 100%;
    }   
</style>
```

and add event listener for resize of window to the end of `drawChart()` method:

```
    ...
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }, false);
}
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/rikup/1/edit)

Comment: its already working. btw, it is possible to run even without style?

Comment: The height and width of the chart have to be defined either in the chart's options or in the style applied to the container div (via inline styles or CSS).  The chart options for height and width take integer values only - they cannot use percents - so you would have to change the values passed in the options with every draw call if you don't want to style the container div.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to remove the blank spaces both sides in the chart, how can I do that?